# c# winForms open forms inside mainform

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have programmed c# application i will post screenshot. In this main form is 3 buttons which opens different forms. Now i decided to modify this application I want to Make one main form with strip menu which will open this forms. I used this code but i don't like or i'm doing something wrong. I don't like because there is child controls(minimize, maximize, close) in parent (please see second picture ):

[image]

Please advice me something. Is MDI good for such job? Thanks!

```
Sell sell = new Sell();
sell.MdiParent = this;
sell.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
sell.Show();`
```

[image]

So my problem is that parent form is not filling when i open child form this is creen how to make that it parent form was filled with child form [image]

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to describe here. You said that you don't *like* MDI, because then each child form gets minimize, maximize, and close buttons? That's how it will work any time you show a new form, whether it's an MDI child or a separate floating window. Can you update your question with any better explanation of what final design you hope to achieve?

Comment: I would have thought that a page control would be more appropriate for your needs, as I understand them

Comment: Thanks for try to help me.   Sell sell = new Sell();
            sell.MdiParent = this;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your latest edit, I assume the reason that your child form's content doesn't fill the screen even when it's maximized is because your content/layout is not flexible.

Wherever you've placed the controls during Design Mode is where they're going to end up at run time, regardless of how big or small you make the window. If the window is too small to contain all of them, they'll either be covered up or you will see scrollbars. Alternatively, if the window is made larger than necessary, you'll see a lot of empty space.

The way around this is either to set the [`Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) and [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) properties of your controls, which causes them to expand and compress to fit the layout of their containing form. You could also place your controls inside a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) or [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) control to help manage their layout.

As far as the question you appeared to be asking originally, I still can't tell if you're opposed to the way an MDI application looks, or if you simply don't understand how to correctly implement it. The clarification comment you offered actually makes things *less* clear to me—you posted a code snippet, but didn't explain what it means. As I wrote in a comment, there's no (non-hackish) way to show a form that doesn't have minimize, maximize, and close buttons (setting the `FormBorderStyle` property to "None" does this, but I think this is a silly solution that simply allows you to use the wrong control for the job—it won't behave like a form, the user won't be able to move it around like a form, etc. so why *use* a form?).

If you truly want to have a single application window with changing content in the center, you should create a series of [`UserControls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx). You can lay out each user control with the necessary child controls, just like you would with a form (using the fluid layout techniques I discussed above), add each user control to your main form, set each control's `Dock` property to "Fill" (so that they fill the entire viewing area), and then write code to simply swap out the currently visible user control in your main form's viewing area. The advantage of using a `UserControl` versus something like a `Panel` is that you consolidate all of your code into a single control, much like you would with a `Form`. You could use a tab control, but if you don't want to show any indication that there are multiple forms (which is what your aim appears to be), this would also be the wrong control for the job.

If you literally want to open child forms inside your main form, as your question title indicates, you should indeed be using MDI. If you don't understand *how* to do this, you'll need to clarify your question further.

Answer (score 1):

Set **MDI Container** property to true for your parent form. It will help.

Comment: *How* will it help? This is not a particularly useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
FormBorderStyle = None
```

for your child forms